# HTML table is adding additional row when calling information from database table

Tags: php, html, database, html-table, row

I seem to be having an issue with my HTML formatting. I am calling the database to display all information within the table on a webpage. I have got the information coming down into the table. Unfortunately the table is adding an additional row to the bottom of the table making 4 rows when in fact there is only 3 rows displaying in the database.

Any idea as to why?

```
<?php
//connect to the server
$link = mysql_connect('*****', '*****', '****'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

mysql_select_db('******'); 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename");

        echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Region</td>
            <td>Cameraman</td>
            <td>Livestream?</td>
            <td>Event Title</td>
            <td>Lecturer</td>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td>Speaker</td>
            <td>ICE Contact</td>
            <td>Venue Address</td>
            <td>Venue Contact</td>
            <td>Additional Comments</td>
            <td>On App?</td>
            </tr>";

        WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['region'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $rows['cameraman'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['livestream'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $rows['eventitle'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['lecturer'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $rows['time'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['speaker'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['icecontact'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['venueaddress'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $rows['venuecontact'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['additioncomments'] . "</td>";  
            echo "<td>" . $rows['onapp'] . "</td>";     
            echo "</tr>";


        endwhile;
            echo "</table>";

?>
```

I have added the link to the page below.

http://cpdonline.tv/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.php

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you have in DB? Also what's the value in `<?php var_dump(mysql_num_rows($query)); ?>`. Please **stop using `mysql_*` functions**. It is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your while loop with the following:

```
WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
            $rows = array_filter($rows);
            if (!empty($rows)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['date'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['region'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $rows['cameraman'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['livestream'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $rows['eventitle'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['lecturer'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $rows['time'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['speaker'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['icecontact'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['venueaddress'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $rows['venuecontact'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['additioncomments'] . "</td>";  
                echo "<td>" . $rows['onapp'] . "</td>";     
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            endwhile;
            echo "</table>";
```

array_filter() function's default behavior will remove all values from array which are equal to `null, 0, '' or false.`

Comment: That has done the trick! Thank you for your help! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have empty data in your database, as many lines are empty

Answer (score 0):

Check your database for empty records or run the query

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE column='';
```